# How to add Age to the failed Test in Allure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

I have integrated Allure in my framework for reporting test results. Allure has most of the benefits I want. Only what I need help for is, how can I add Age to the failed test. Google search is giving me the Allure capability for @Flaky...but that is not what I want.   My particular requirement is, if a test was working fine till 100th jenkins build, and stated failing from 101, till 129 (today), it should show the age as "29 Builds (Or something)" Is there a way to achieve this using Allure ?  Or any other jenkins plug-in which do this for me through Allure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to do it with Allure framework right out of the box.

What you can try to do is to write a piece of code that will make those calculations for you and then you can attach a file to Allure report with your calculations.

I don't think you are gonna do it so there is also another option, maybe it's good for you.

**Why don't you try to use "Retries" tab or "History" tab instead?**

**Retries:**
[image]

**History:**
[image]